# Cannot start NFS Gateway - Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I am unable to start NFS Gateway in Cloudera. It gives me error `Supervisor returned FATAL. Please check the role log file, stderr, or stdout`

But the only strange thing that I can observe in stdout is

```
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
+ '[' 1 -ne 0 ']'
+ echo 'Cannot connect to port 111.'
+ return 1
+ '[' 1 -eq 1 ']'
+ echo 'No portmap or rpcbind service is running on this host. Please start portmap or rpcbind service before attempting to start the NFS Gateway role on this host.'
+ exit 1
```

I've tried to change port 111 to 1111 but it didn't help. Any ideas what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have rpcbind running:

```
sudo service rpcbind start
```

Answer (score 3):

In the latest RHEL release use `systemctl` command to introspect and control systemd.

```
   systemctl status rpcbind.service # Check status of rpcbind
   systemctl start rpcbind.service  # Start rpcbind
   systemctl stop rpcbind.service   # Stop rpcbind
```

The old /etc/init.d/ scripts are still available for some services for legacy support and backward compatibility.